# How do i configure fldigi for a UK QTH?

Tags: europe, fldigi

Location configuration in fldigi for Ubuntu only offers 'state' and 'county'. How do i enable it to accept non-US QTH?

Comment: Have you looked in a config file in ~/.fldigi ?  Maybe you can put the info in there manually?

Answer (score 1):

`$HOME/.fldigi/data/SQSO.txt`, which is the file that contains US states and counties, can be edited to add other QTHs. The layout is fairly clear - just added a line:

```
United Kingdom, GBR,Cornwall,SW
```

Once that is done, restart fldigi and the new QTH details will be available from the configuration dialog.